# Insert comment in ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I need to annotate my JSX with comments for a ternary operator, but the following doesn't work:

```
                {
                    errorObj.message
                    ?
                        <Error msg={formatError(errorObj)} /> 
                    :
                        {/* If the current Route is non-Home, and appData/userInfo have not been loaded yet, 
                            redirect to NotAuthorized */}
                        (currentRoute && currentRoute !== '/' && (appData === null || userInfo === null))
                        ?
                            <NotAuthorized />
                        :
                            <Main userInfo={userInfo} appData={appData} />
                 }

Error: TypeError: {} is not a function
```

at the first comment line. If I remove the comment it works.

Comment: Given that you're already _in_ JavaScript braces {} without JSX, why have you added another pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already in the context of a JavaScript expression when using the conditional operator:

```
errorObj.message
    ? <Error msg={formatError(errorObj)} />
    :
```

Brackets `{}` are used in JSX when delimiting JavaScript expressions, as opposed to JSX markup. Remove the inner `{}`s:

```
{
    errorObj.message
        ?
        <Error msg={formatError(errorObj)} />
        :
        /* If the current Route is non-Home, and appData/userInfo have not been loaded yet, 
                redirect to NotAuthorized */
        (currentRoute && currentRoute !== '/' && (appData === null || userInfo === null))
            ?
            <NotAuthorized />
            :
            <Main userInfo={userInfo} appData={appData} />
}
```

Another possibility would be to use an IIFE (or a separate named function), which some might prefer for readability:

```
{
    (() => {

        if (errorObj.message) {
            return <Error msg={formatError(errorObj)} />;
        }
        /* If the current Route is non-Home, and appData/userInfo have not been loaded yet, 
                redirect to NotAuthorized */
        if (currentRoute && currentRoute !== '/' && (appData === null || userInfo === null)) {
            return <NotAuthorized />;
        }
        return <Main userInfo={userInfo} appData={appData} />
    })()
}
```